# Django: Two models with OneToOneField vs a single model

Tags: django, database-design, django-models

Let's imagine a I have a simple model Recipe:

```
class Recipe(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=constants.NAME_MAX_LENGTH)
    preparation_time = models.DurationField()
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(default=constants.RECIPE_DEFAULT_THUMBNAIL, upload_to=constants.RECIPE_CUSTOM_THUMBNAIL_LOCATION)
    ingredients = models.TextField()
    description = models.TextField()
```

I would like to create a view listing all the available recipes where only name, thumbnail, preparation_time and first 100 characters of description will be used. In addition I will have a dedicated view to render all remaining details for a single recipe.

From the efficiency point of view, since description may be a long text, would it make sense to store the extra information in a separate model, let's say 'RecipeDetails' which would not be extracted in a list view but only in a detailed view (maybe using prefetch_related method)? I am thinking about something along:

```
class Recipe(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=constants.NAME_MAX_LENGTH)
    preparation_time = models.DurationField()
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(default=constants.DEFAULT_THUMBNAIL, upload_to=constants.CUSTOM_THUMBNAIL_LOCATION)
    description_preview = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class RecipeDetails(models.Model):
    recipe = models.OneToOneField(Recipe, related_name="details", primary_key=True)        
    ingredients = models.TextField()
    description = models.TextField()
```

In my recent online searches people seem to suggest that OneToOneField should be used only for two purposes: 1. inheritance and 2. extending existing models. In other cases two models should be merged into one. This may suggest I am missing something here. Is this a reasonable use of OneToOneField or does it only add to a complexity of an overall design?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> inheritance

Don't do that, because inheritance would only be useful if you have baseclass/subclass relationship. The classic example is animal and cat/dog, in which the cats/dogs all have some basic properties that could be extracted, but your `Recipe` and `RecipeDetail` don't.

> From the efficiency point of view, since description may be a long
>   text, would it make sense to store the extra information in a separate
>   model

Storing extra information in a separate model doesn't improve any efficiency. The underline database would create something like a `ForeignKey` field and plus `unique=True` to make sure the uniqueness. As far as I concerned, `OneToOneField` is only useful when your original model is hard to change, e.g., it is from third-party packages or some other awkward situations. Otherwise I still consider adding them to the `Recipe` model. In this case, you can manage your model easily while avoiding having some extra lookups like `recipe.recipedetail.description`, you can just do `recipe.description`.

Comment: Something not related, your model name should always use single form instead of plural form, django will add plural form when needed.

Comment: Does it mean that the code "for r in Recipe.objects.all(): print r.name" will have the same performance regardless whether description is a OneToOneField or a (potentially long) TextField? For the purpose of this question I treat OneToOneField and ForeignKey interchangeably.

Comment: I don't know where did you get the idea about your performance concern, but accessing field `name` has nothing to do with what other fields look like. What I suggested is just from pure code structure point of view, and I was saying that you don't gain anything by adding details as `OneToOne` field, so just put all of them in `Recipe` model. A model with many fields doesn't make it more complex, nor less performant.

Comment: True, I am more concerned about "Recipe.objects.all()" statement which (maybe wrongly) will evaluate to a set  of a lot larger objects if I store description directly in Recipe class. In particular, if I don't use description field, it seems like a significant overhead to read all the descriptions for all the recipes if I just want to list them.

Comment: `TextField` is really not scary at all unless you have millions of records. Also, django already has tools to fit your needs. You can do `Recipe.objects.values('name', 'preparation_time')`, it will do `SELECT name, preparation_time FROM Recipe` behind the scene, so your text field will not be in the cache.https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values

Comment: Recipe.objects.values() is the solution I needed. I agree, it is a lot cleaner than splitting the model into two separate ones. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not reasonable to split your Recipes. First, your model should contain all properties for being a "Recipe" (and a recipe without ingredients is not a recipe at all). Second, if you want to improve performance, then use the [Django's Cache Framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/cache/#django-s-cache-framework) (it was created exactly for improving performance issues). Third, keep it simple and do not over-engineering your development cycle. Do you really need to improve performance right now?

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

First mistake in development, you are thinking in efficiency before your first version is running.

Try to have now a first version, that runs, and later you can think in be more faster based in use cases with your first version. After this you can check if a model and relations, or only a new field in model or using Django Cache for views can do the work.

Your think in efficiency first will be "de-normalize" your Database btw, when one update in the model with full description is done, you need to launch one update to the model with "description-preview" field. trigger in database level? python code for update in app level? nightmares in code design ... before your code runs.